# Anchor tag completely un-clickable in IE11

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer

Hi guys so I have been researching everywhere and cannot find a solution for this problem. Here is the exact line of code.

```
'<a id="auto_refinance_loan_documents_save_link" ' + ((scope.styleAsBtn) ? 'class="btn btn-primary"' : '') + '>' + linkText + '</a>';
```

We are using angularJS so you can pretty much ignore all the other stuff, but it is a simple anchor tag with bootstrap btn class. It works perfectly fine on all browsers, besides IE11 of course. The issue is you can not click the a tag at all. It does absolutely nothing when clicking it.

Comment: "`so you can pretty much ignore all the other stuff`" :: Edit your code and present  version with all the parts you think we should ignore removed.

Comment: @Martin ignore the id... I wanted to include the bootstrap class because I didn't know if that would be throwing something off

Comment: We can't comment on the bootstrap class unless you can also show us what that CSS does?

Comment: Can you also show us the Source ouput of the anchor in the destination browser (IE / Edge) ?

Comment: You haven't given your anchor any actions, or at least you are not sharing that part of the code. You don't have an `ng-click` or an `href` attribute. You have not shown any code that adds a click listener. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: After adding the href attribute, it seems that the link works well, try to add the href attribute and use F12 to check the html element. You could also check my [sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ximEv.gif), the button is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If an `a` tag doesn't contain a `href` attribute, it's considered by the browser to be a placeholder for a future link, and remains unclickable. If you want to use this as a clickable link without following any URL, you can use a hash as the `href`:

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```

It is mentioned in the [W3 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#element-attrdef-a-href):

> The href attribute on a and area elements is not required; when those elements do not have href attributes they do not create hyperlinks.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not fix the issue for ie11